# Placing Cursor at the end of the text in inputbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am trying to place my cursor at the end of text in the input box in **Google Search Box**.  I have tried all the possible solutions posted over the internet but none of them working out.  I am able to set text using `val()` function, but unable to place cursor at the end of the text after setting its value.

I have already tried `focus()` method and other solutions which have been posted on Stack Overflow.  **I have tested all those posted solution using developer console.**

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: The devtools console is in a different frame which steals focus from the page so your tests were meaningless.

Comment: I also tested with chrome extension, it does not gain focus at all.  Only sets text!

Comment: If `Google Search Box` is the one on the default new tab page then it's not a normal DOM input element but just a "jumper" that redirects to the address bar which is a native UI control, not DOM.

Comment: Thanks for info, but I need solution

Comment: In DOM of the new tab page I see `jsaction` attribute that does what you need on `mousedown` e.g. `document.getElementById('q').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true}));`

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that!